# Fragment color - -how to set it to transparent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, colors, fragment

What will be better: set *transparent* color in the fragments and then use color from the activity_main.xml **or** set color in the fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually is better to declare non transparent background color of fragment because in case you have multiple fragments one over another, when you click on empty space on top most fragment, the click event will be transferred to back fragment and in case you have a button on the bottom fragment, will accept the touch event. You will get very weird behavior, so yeah, put background color on each fragment. 
Don't be worried about performance. It will not affect it.